# Three-dimensional gaussian integral with $(x + y + z)^2$ term

Tags: calculus, 3d, gaussian-integral

I need to analytically perform the following integral:

$$\mathcal{I} = \int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{\frac{-r^2}{2}}(x + y + z)^2 dx dy dz$$

I know the standard way to perform multi-dimensional gaussian integrals is to split them up and calculate each dimension seperately, but I do not know how to deal with $(x + y + z)^2$ term.

Comment: Expand it into its pieces, then break each piece up as you say

Comment: By expanding it, a lot of nonlinear terms appear, which make it so that it cannot be split up.

Comment: Is $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$?

Comment: @Empy2's idea works better than you might think. Using $e^{-r^2/2}dxdydz=e^{-x^2/2}dxe^{-y^2/2}dye^{-z^2/2}dz$, $\mathcal{I}$ becomes a sum of products of three integrals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $X,\,Y,\,Z$ be three $N(0,\,1)$ IIDs so $X+Y+Z\sim N(0,\,3)$. Then$$\mathcal{I}=(2\pi)^{3/2}\Bbb E(X+Y+Z)^2=3(2\pi)^{3/2}.$$